# "is a bullet" in levelhelper

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

What is  "is a bullet" property used for in levelhelper? Also , in a game like angry birds,
the birds are reloaded in the spring ...How to maintain the count? and how to reload the bullet in the spring if im making an angry bird like game using levelhelper.

Comment: your question is unclear - post some code?

Answer (score 1):

From the box2d manual http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

> **Bullets**
>
> Game simulation usually generates a sequence of images that are played at some frame rate. This is called discrete simulation. In discrete simulation, rigid bodies can move by a large amount in one time step. If a physics engine doesn't account for the large motion, you may see some objects incorrectly pass through each other. This effect is called tunneling.
>
> By default, Box2D uses continuous collision detection (CCD) to prevent dynamic bodies from tunneling through static bodies. This is done by sweeping shapes from their old position to their new positions. The engine looks for new collisions during the sweep and computes the time of impact (TOI) for these collisions. Bodies are moved to their first TOI and then halted for the remainder of the time step.
>
> Normally CCD is not used between dynamic bodies. This is done to keep performance reasonable. In some game scenarios you need dynamic bodies to use CCD. For example, you may want to shoot a high speed bullet at a stack of dynamic bricks. Without CCD, the bullet might tunnel through the bricks.
>
> Fast moving objects in Box2D can be labeled as bullets. Bullets will perform CCD with both static and dynamic bodies. You should decide what bodies should be bullets based on your game design. If you decide a body should be treated as a bullet, use the following setting.
>
> `bodyDef.bullet = true;`
>
> The bullet flag only affects dynamic bodies.
>
> Box2D performs continuous collision sequentially, so bullets may miss fast moving bodies.